# Data missing after page refresh

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Route:

```
App.Router.map(function()
{
    this.resource("login", { path: "/login"});
    this.resource("contacts", { path: "/contacts"}, function ()
    {
        this.resource("contact", { path: ":contact_id"}, function()
        {
            this.route("new");
            this.route("edit");
        });     
    });
});

App.ContactsIndexRoute = App.AuthenticatedRoute.extend(
{
    model: function()
    {
        return  App.Contact.find();
    }
});

App.ContactIndexRoute = App.AuthenticatedRoute.extend(
{
    model: function()
    {
        return this.modelFor("contact");
    },

    setupController: function(controller, model)
    {
        controller.set("content", model);
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
App.ContactsIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend(
{
    setProperties: ['full_name']
});

App.ContactEditControllerr = Ember.ObjectController.extend(
{

});

App.ContactIndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(
{
});
```

When I go to #/contacts I get the full list of the contacts from the server. If I go to #/contacts/1 I will get all the data but if I refresh that page, the data is gone and I'm left with bare HTML. The question is how to *preserve* model in nested resource so it's there after page refresh?

Comment: To me works http://jsbin.com/ucanam/666/edit. Are you using the lastest version?

Comment: Yes, I am using the latest version. With FIxtures it works fine bot not with REST adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have simulate the problem and your code works. Even with the rest adapter.

http://jsbin.com/ucanam/669#/contacts/1

I think that your problem is your returned json. It have to match the following:

`Several resources`

GET /contacts
Status: 200

{
  contacts: [
    { id: 1, full_name: 'Tom dale' }, 
    { id: 2, full_name: 'Yehuda Katz'}
  ]
}

`Unique resource`

GET /contacts/1
Status: 200

{
  contact: { 
    id: 1, full_name: 'Tom dale' 
  }
}

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did some changes and reorganised my code and now it's fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Could be that there is some problem querying your datasource for an individual record. Try loading contacts in the base route so that it gets called on both contact and contacts.

```
App.ContactsRoute = App.AuthenticatedRoute.extend({
  model: function() {
    return  App.Contact.find();
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm obviously doing something wrong because after I refresh #/contacts/1, I get a REST call to /contacts/1 and server responds but  my page is empty. So, i'm doing it wrong somewhere in the template maybe?